# Jooq custom delete method throw ERROR: cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jooq, spring-boot-test

I use Springboot3 and Jooq to create my project and define a custom delete method `deleteByUsername` follow [jooq delete guide](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/delete-statement/)

```java
@Repository
public class UserRepository extends UserDao {

  @Autowired
  public UserRepository(Configuration configuration) {
    super(configuration);
  }

  /* --- some query method can run sucessful in run and test---
   ........
  */

  public void deleteByUsername(String username) {
    ctx().delete(USER).where(USER.USERNAME.eq(username)).execute();
  }
}
```

The UserRepository is extend UserDao so `ctx()` is return a DSLContext instance.

```java
@Repository
public class UserDao extends AbstractSpringDAOImpl<UserRecord, jooq.tables.pojos.User, Long> {

    /**
     * Create a new UserDao without any configuration
     */
    public UserDao() {
        super(User.USER, jooq.tables.pojos.User.class);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch records that have <code>id IN (values)</code>
     */
    public List<jooq.tables.pojos.User> fetchById(Long... values) {
        return fetch(User.USER.ID, values);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch a unique record that has <code>id = value</code>
     */
    public jooq.tables.pojos.User fetchOneById(Long value) {
        return fetchOne(User.USER.ID, value);
    }

    .....more
}
```

UserDao is generate by jooq code generate plugin when if you set up with

```kotlin
generate.apply {
   isDeprecated = false
   isRecords = true
   isImmutablePojos = false
   isFluentSetters = true
   isDaos = true // will create dao layer by jooq
   isSpringDao = true
   isSpringAnnotations = true
}
```

All *Dao is extend DAOImpl, and ctx() is the way to get DSLContext in dao layer

```java
public abstract class DAOImpl<R extends UpdatableRecord<R>, P, T> implements DAO<R, P, T> {

    private final Table<R>     table;
    private final Class<P>     type;
    private RecordMapper<R, P> mapper;
    private Configuration      configuration;


    /**
     * Inject a configuration.
     * <p>
     * This method is maintained to be able to configure a <code>DAO</code>
     * using Spring. It is not exposed in the public API.
     */
    public /* non-final */ void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
        this.mapper = ((FieldsImpl<R>) table.recordType()).mapper(this.configuration = Tools.configuration(configuration), type);
    }

    public /* non-final */ DSLContext ctx() {
        return configuration().dsl();
    }

}
```

### Problem

When i run `deleteByUsername` in springboot test it was failed, and throw exception below.

But `jooqDeleteRunSuccess` run suceess. The `userRepository.delete` method which defined in `jooqDeleteRunSuccess` is jooq generated dao layer's method, it's not custom method.

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class SignE2ETest {

  @Autowired private WebTestClient webClient;

  @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Test
  void jooqDeleteRunSuccess() {
    User stubUser = new User();
    stubUser.setUsername("test_5fab32c22a3e");
    stubUser.setPassword("test_eab28b939ba1");
    userRepository.insert(stubUser);
    userRepository.delete(userRepository.fetchOneByUsername("test_5fab32c22a3e"));
  }

  @Test
  void myDeleteRunFailed() {
    User stubUser = new User();
    stubUser.setUsername("test_5fab32c22a3e");
    stubUser.setPassword("test_eab28b939ba1");
    userRepository.insert(stubUser);
    userRepository.deleteByUsername("test_5fab32c22a3e");
  }
}
```

```java
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [delete from "mjga"."user" where "mjga"."user"."username" = ?]; ERROR: cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction
 at org.jooq_3.18.6.POSTGRES.debug(Unknown Source)
 at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3470)
 at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3458)
 at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:801)
 at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:360)
 at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDelegatingQuery.execute(AbstractDelegatingQuery.java:115)
 at com.mjga.repository.UserRepository.deleteByUsername(UserRepository.java:61)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
.....
```

#### Question

As you see there is no explicit config to set postgresql to READ-ONLY mode, I don't know why this READ-ONLY exception happend?

Why `myDeleteRunFailed` throw READ-ONLY exception but `jooqDeleteRunSuccess` not?

How to fix it?

#### Enviroment

- springboot-3.1.2
- jooq-3.18.6
- postgresql-15.4

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.18.6")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.18.6")
    implementation("com.auth0:java-jwt:4.4.0")
    implementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.19.0")
    implementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.19.0")
    implementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:1.19.0")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docker-compose")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers:3.1.2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docker-compose")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    jooqGenerator("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
}
```

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: 'postgres:15.4'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - ${DATABASE_PORT}:5432
    volumes:
      - ./db.d/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ${DATABASE_STORE}:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: on-failure
```

I have checked my DB read_only status

```sql
SHOW default_transaction_read_only;
SHOW transaction_read_only;

off
off
```

Comment: It is unclear what `ctx()` returns, but I'm assuming that it returns an implementation `DSLContext` that is configured for a read-only transaction. I didn't find an implementation of `ctx()` in the jOOQ code, so I'm assuming it's a custom method and that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Your setup doesn't hint at your using jOOQ's own transaction API (which I wouldn't recommend anyway, if you're using jOOQ with Spring), and even if you did, jOOQ doesn't (yet) support readonly transactions, so I'd look for this configuration somewhere in your Spring Boot setup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Guss Sorry, I've added `ctx()` detail to the question and it's not my custom method. Thank you Guss!

@Community Sorry, I've added more details to the question, reorganized my language, and described my issue

Comment: @LukasEder Thank you Lukas. I've added more details to my question especially about extend Dao layer part.

If the problem is READ-ONLY setting in springboot, I think `userRepository.delete` should throw exception like  `userRepository.deleteByUsername` but it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as Frisk and Lukas Eder mentioned, was due to some Spring Boot setup making the transactional behavior default to "read-only."

When using JOOQ with Spring, the DAO layer extends `AbstractSpringDAOImpl`, which has the `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` annotation at the class level. This caused `UserRepository` to be treated as read-only for all its methods.

To solve the problem, I added the `@Transactional` annotation at the method level to override the class-level annotation, like this:

```java
@Transactional
public void deleteByUsername(String username) {
    ctx().delete(USER).where(USER.USERNAME.eq(username)).execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction" indicates that you are attempting to perform a DELETE operation in a read-only transaction, which does not allow modifying the database.

So I guess the jooq method "jooqDeleteRunSuccess" initiated a writable transaction before executing the DELETE operation

But your personal method "myDeleteRunFailed" only get a DSLContext instance, but not initiate a writable transaction

You can use this codes before your method and try again

```
DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
```